# Tailwind CSS not allowing Next.js to run

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I don't know why but when I install Tailwind in my brand new empty Next.js project I get this error after running `npm run dev`.

**ERROR**

> error - ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/34157).rules[3].oneOf[11].use[1](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/34157)!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/34157).rules[3].oneOf[11].use[2]!./styles/globals.css
> /Users/andregomes/Desktop/Note/todo/tailwind.config.js:6
>
> SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
> Import trace for requested module:
> ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/34157).rules[3].oneOf[11].use[1](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/34157)!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/34157).rules[3].oneOf[11].use[2]!./styles/globals.css
> ./styles/globals.css

The best answer I found for this issue was [in this Next.js discussion thread](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/34157), but I already checked and I don't use `tailwindcss/nesting`. I just followed the regular installation instructions for Next.js and Tailwind.

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
​
    // Or if using `src` directory:
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**postcss.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

**package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "todo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@next/font": "13.1.3",
    "eslint": "8.32.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.1.3",
    "next": "13.1.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4"
  }
}
```

**globals.css**

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: your code seems correct. try different versions maybe one of the related packages causing bug: `"postcss": "^8.4.13",   "tailwindcss": "^3.0.24",    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.5",`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try after removing line number 6 (blank line) from tailwind.config.js and do **npm run dev** again. must be some special character at line 6.

Comment: OMG... I completely overlooked that, yes that was the issue! thank you